# Shift operator on integers

Tags: c

I have the following function:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint64_t dtally(uint64_t x)
{
    uint64_t t = 0;
    while (x){ t += 1 << ((x%10) * 6), x /= 10;
    return t;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", dtally(39));
    return 0;
}
```

when I pass a number as 39 i understand should return the following value

```
18014398509481984
```

but it returns this value:

```
4456448
```

because returns this value and not what you expected?

Comment: The `int` type is typically only 32 bits, even on 64-bit systems. Use e.g. `int64_t` instead.

Comment: Please do not edit your question in a way that significantly changes its meaning.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problem with your code (in fact it is the same problem twice).

First, `t` is an `int`, which is usually a 32 bit integer (and at least 16 bits). So 2^54, will not fit there. You have to use a 64 bit type for `t`. But your problem will persist.

The second problem is trickier: `1 << ((x % 10) * 6)` perform a shift operation on the literal `1`. But `1` is an `int`. So `1 << 54` will return `0` (the one is shifted out of the 32  bits of memory, then added to `t`). To solve this, you can cast the literal `1` to int64_t or use the literal `1LL` (type long long) instead.

So you should have something like this:

```
int count(int x)
{
    int64_t t = 0;
    while (x) t += 1LL << ((x % 10) * 6), x /= 10;
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`18014398509481984` is probably too big for an `int` on your platform.

Check this by testing `sizeof(int)`. If that's 4 then the largest number you can represent is a little over 2 billion. It might even be only 2 (in which case the largest `int` would be 32767).

You could use `int64_t` instead which is 64 bits (and available since C99; although a platform is not compelled to support it).

Don't forget to suffix any literals with LL which denotes a 64 bit type.

Comment: but using "uint64_t" also get the same result I edited the code shown above